# The best approach to integrate a rapidly increasing function $f(x)$ near the upper limit of $x$ using Gaussian Quadrature Method

Tags: normal-distribution, quadrature

This is my first time posting my question here, and I hope I won’t violate any rules or post duplicate questions.

I am currently implementing a parameterization method of models to reduce the computing time.
$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\Bbb dx$$
I need to get the integral of $f(x)$ for $x$ between 0 and 1. The value of $f(x)$ is obtained from running a model, which takes significant time. Therefore, I wanted to use the Gaussian Quadrature Method for the integration. Specifically, we can use $x_k$ (abscissa) and $w_k$ (weights).

Therefore, the integral of $f(x)$ can be approximated as
$$\sum_{k=1}^n w_k f(x_k)$$

However, as shown in the figure, the function $f(x)$ we are dealing with rapidly increases as $x$ approaches 1, close to the exponential function. Due to the shape of $f(x)$, $n=5$ (shown in this example) does not capture very large values of $f(x)$ near $x = 1$ since it assumes a smooth polynomial (blue line in the figure). As a result, the integral using the Gaussian Quadrature method gives an underestimated integral value.
Increasing $n$ in the Gaussian Quadrature method would certainly give a better answer of the integral, but more data points mean much longer model computing time.
Therefore, without increasing $n$ numbers significantly, I am wondering what is the best approach to obtain the integral of $f(x)$ in this case.
I found variation formula of the Gaussian Quadrature method (e.g., Gauss-Jacobi quadrature), or adaptive Gaussian quadrature method, but not fully understood which method is expected to give a better accuracy with the fixed $n$ number for the rapidly increasing function at the upper limit.
The Adaptive Gaussian method divides the interval of $x$ (0 and 1) into two parts (0-0.5 and 0.5-1), but I am wondering if we can consider different lengths of $x$ intervals (e.g., 0-0.9 and 0.9-1.0) to describe the rapid increase of $f(x)$ near $x=1$.

In addition, if we know the truth of the integral of $f(x)$ between 0 and 1, and we can get the error term, $\epsilon$ (the solution from Gaussian Quadrature minus truth), can the error term ($\epsilon$) be applied to the Gaussian Quadrature formula as an additive term as follows?
$$\sum_{k=1}^n w_k f(x_k)+\epsilon $$

If you can give any insights, that would be great.

Example of $f(x)$

[image: Example of <span class=]$f(x)$ click here" />

Comment: Do you know anything about the behaviour of $f$ near $1$? If so, you could use weights or a transform to take that behaviour into account analytically. For instance, [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Other_forms) you can find a list of quadrature methods suitable for various common types of behaviour at the boundary.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The shape of function depends on the spectral region (the f(x) actually represents a cumulative function of gas absorption coefficient), but generally, f(x) follows the shapes of exponential functions.

Comment: Do you know the rate parameter for the exponential function that $f(x)$ resembles (i.e. the $\lambda$ in $\mathrm e^{\lambda x}$)?

Comment: The function $f(x)$ does not exactly follow the exponential function, but the $\lambda$ can be obtained by fitting. In addition, the $lamda$ value various by cases, unfortunately..